# Bind data without writing format to the DB

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, data-binding, string-formatting

This is in a grid in an Asp page. If I try to bind a textBox with a date formatted like this to a date column in SQL DB I have no problems:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="requestDate" runat="server" Width="200px Text='<%# Bind("requestDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

However, If I try to bind a value to an Int column in the DB, like this:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="valueTT" runat="server" Width="128px" Text='<%# Bind("valueTT", "{0:C0}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

it generates an exception, "incorrect format string". Without the formatting it works fine. I am not really familiar with this. On one side I need to show the format to the user, on the other side would be better not to write the value in the db with the format. How do I solve this problem?